# How to change the icon of a PrimeNG-Dropdown

Tags: icons, font-awesome, primeng, angular7, primeng-dropdowns

I've been trying to change the icon that primeNG provides by default. I'm close, but there is some stuff i don't get.

I've created a var in my component.ts with the value of a font-awesome icon.
In the template i've asigned an attribute [dropdownIcon] with the value of the var.
When i check in the browser displays an empty square.
Debugging i've seen that if i uncheked the attribute 'content' of .ui-dropdown-trigger-icon:before, displays the icon properly, but i've no idea of how to remove that in my code.

If possible i would like to know to how to remove the border of the box, i've already tried but nothing worked.

**header.component.ts**

```
card="fas fa-id-card fa-lg";
```

**header.component.html**

```
<p-dropdown [dropdownIcon]="card" [options]="products" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct" optionLabel="label" placeholder="Registro"></p-dropdown>
```

**header.component.scss**

I've tried, unsuccesfully (displays nothing)

```
:host {
  ::ng-deep .ui-dropdown-trigger-icon:before{
    content: "";
  }
}
```

The captures of the debugging:

[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ptif.jpg)
[How get's displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whyQ6.jpg)
[Result of the unckeck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kZ6G.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
.fa-id-card:before {
    content: "\f2c2" !important;
}
```

To remove box border add property to p-dropdown:

```
[style]="{'border': 'none'}"
```

This is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dahwv7)

Comment: Yes, worked great, both of them. I add it to styles.scss, didn't need to add it to the component.scss. Doesn't look really clean but works perfect. Thanks a lot!